# can print with cout but can't create new string with same object?

Tags: c++, string, cout

I'm new to C++ and I encountered a case where a script directly prints an output to prompt like this:

```
cout << setw(10) << Object->GetAuthor().GetId() << " ";
cout << Object->GetDate() << " ";
cout << Object->GetCaseNumber() << " ";
```

This works in the script and prints to the console, now I would like to save the strings instead of printing it to prompt but the fact is that this are not strings in this sample they could be int variable or other things.

I don't understand why `cout << Object->GetType() << " ";` works while `string x = Object->GetType()` doesn't.

And is there a way to save what's being printed to the console as strings?

Comment: What does GetType return? The simple answer is that cout::operator<< can accept that type, but no string constructor can.  If all else fails there is std::stringstream

Comment: Replace `cout` with a stringstream object, and use its `str` function to extract the completed string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are streams that print to strings.

Like this:

```
#include <sstream>

// ...

std::ostringstream s;
s << setw(10) << Object->GetAuthor().GetId() << " ";
s << Object->GetDate() << " ";
s << Object->GetCaseNumber() << " ";

std::string result = s.str();
```

The reason

```
string x = Object->GetType()
```

doesn't work is that `Object->GetType()` doesn't return something that can be assigned to a string.

The `<<` operator "knows" how to convert many things to a string representation (the technical term is that it is *overloaded* for numerous different types).

Answer (score 0):

`Cout <<` knows about several types it can print, such as `int`, `string` and `bool`. It can also print object addresses if it doesn't know how to handle those objects.

The problem here is that string isn't that clever so the conversion may not work. You need to make sure that `GetType` returns something that can be converted to a string properly

Comment: That's not a helpful solution. Why not recommend stringstream?

Comment: If GetType returns an object, Springsteen won't help

Comment: It returns an object that supports operator << with a stream so probably it will.

Comment: It will probably print the object address

Comment: No it will call operator << on the object or refuse to compile. If it works with cout it will work with streamstream unless the operator is implemented in an unusual way.